# How do I create this column that adds one whenever the value changes?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to add the column 'city_group' below.
The table is ordered by the day.

I've tried using window functions but couldn't figure out a simple way to do this.
Hoping somebody can point me in the right direction!

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: and which database are you using please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: I am using Postgres

Answer (score 2):

[Window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-window.html) will help you. You will need to combine two:

- `lag` to detect change
- `sum` to roll up change flags provided by `lag` into group ids

  ```
  SELECT day, city, sum(change) over (order by day) as city_group
    FROM (SELECT day, city,
                 case when city != coalesce(lag(city) over (order by day), '') then 1 else 0 end as change
            FROM t) _;
  ```

->[Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kDGdX8wdbWZMkVT3j2fxcy/0)